# Android : What priority is a mixed FCM message

Tags: android, firebase, notifications

Android alert notification messages are "High" priority by default.
Android data only notification messages are "Low" priority by default.

What priority is an alert notification, which ***also*** carries data (using content-available).

We require high priority notifications, however, it seems that when our App is in the background and a notification arrives, the Title/Body are consumed by the OS.  This means that when the user selects the notification from the notification tray, this information is missing in the provided Intent.

We are therefore obliged to pass these (Title/Body) fields as data, with every high priority alert notification.

Does doing this affect the priority of the message, and, if it does affect it, what is the workaround?

Also, is there a way of discovering what priority was actually used for a received message?

Comment: The way to discover what priority was actually used for a received message is to examine the "google.original_priority" and "google.delivered_priority" key value pairs passed with the Intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the sender side, you send a mixed message with the priority you decide. There is no impact.
The difference is just, that when a message contains `data` you get the callback in your FCMService, so your app wakes up.
If there is no `data` part, your app will not wake up before the user clicks the notification.

In general, this is the only question that matters: Do you want to wake up when the message *arrives* or just when the user *clicks* the notification?

If your message contains `data`, the OS will not post the notification. This part is up to you then.
We work with data-Message only as we want to have more control over the notification and we *need* to wake up when it arrives.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I am interested in is whether sending data with a notification will impact delivery speed (in either foreground or background).  In background we want the user to be alerted by the incoming notification as soon as possible, so delivery speed of the notification to produce the audio alert is important to us too.

Comment: We use FCM for incoming call pushes in a Voip app, which is _highly_ time critical. Just send as high priority and it's there almost instantly. a few hundred msec is the normal delay.

Comment: Is there any effect of Doze mode (i.e. maintenance windows) affecting your data only messages?

Comment: No. data-only always arrives, as long as: - background data is allowed for the app, battery optimization is disabled for the app and unlimited data must be enabled. this is that what all push-apps recommend - from whatsapp to skype to... name any messaging client...
But the user must enable this in the settings of the phone - an app has _no way_ to set this automatically. it's a setting that must be done by the user